# JSP template: is there command for FOR or FOREACH iteration

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Im completely newbie in JSP:)

But Im fixing a SPRING/JSP appication. My question is if there is any template command  which iterates through collection/table? Like FOREACH or FOR?

Any documentation/examples for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSTL tag library for this.
First, you have to add jstl tag library to your JSP page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

and for iterating the list:

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="element"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${element.status}</td>
    <td>${element.requestType}</td>
    <td>${element.requestedFor}</td>
    <td>${element.timeSubmitted}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can also use JSP scriptlets (`<% java code %>`) but it's generally not a good idea to mix different languages in the same file. This is just in case you can't use the JSTL tag library.

Comment: any example for FOR if possible?